# Spring web 4 config InternalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".html") not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I try to create Spring 4 project using Java annotations for configuration.

My config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="app.controllers")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp"); // Problem if use .html       
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

controller

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView main() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("index");
    return mav;      
}
...
```

I don't want to use `.jsp` files, but `.html`. I tried to change the code to `resolver.setSuffix(".html");` but got page not found error. The controller works with `.jsp`.

Comment: Can you post your `web.xml`, your controller code and the URL you tested it with?

Comment: I use java based configuration without web.xml. I have index.jsp and index.html file in view folder. I try use `localhost:8080/myproject/`. Controller added to post.

Comment: Try renaming index.html. say renamedindex.html.

Comment: Reading JavaDoc of `InternalResourceViewResolver` might give you a hint why it's not working: "Convenient subclass of UrlBasedViewResolver that supports InternalResourceView (i.e. Servlets and JSPs) and subclasses such as JstlView. ".